# Why do my bones displace model objects?

Tags: bones

Sometimes when i move objects around the attached bones displace the objects. Why does this happen.

Is it correct to assume that bones should NOT overlap with a model poly? Would this prevent object displacements upon object move?

Answer (score 1):

While an armature has not been adjusted in pose mode the object it deforms can be moved without being deformed. Once an armature has been moved in pose mode and the object is moved in object mode without the armature some weird deformation can happen. This is caused by the way the armature and object are linked together.

Once an object and armature have been linked, they need to move together as one. Normally the armature will be the parent of the object and should be moved in object or pose mode to relocate the object.